# Google Analytics: Tracking multi categories where a page belongs

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a content driven website, where each content item belongs to many different categories. 
For example, article "A" belongs to the categories "cat1", "cat3", "cat4" and article "B" belongs to the categories "cat2", "cat3", "cat4".
The number of categories is very big (around 800) and the number of articles more than 10.000.

I want to know all the pageviews of articles that belong to a given category. 
Researching google analalytics I didnt find any tool that allows me to do that.
I investgated if I could misuse the campaigns to do it, but the only way would be to rewrite the urls (in order for the campaigns to work), and I dont want to touch my very nice urls.

I tried doing it with events, but it was messing up my bounce rate (since an event meant that the users were actually doing something, so the page was not counted as "bounced").

Has anyone any idea of what I could do to record my categories?
The same solution could be applied to tags in a blog post. (Lets say you wanted to know all the pageviews of all blog posts that have the tag "travel").

Thanks
Koyan

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I didnt manage to do exactly what I wanted, but canibalising the custom fields I managed to do something very close.

I put in my ga code the following:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Cat', '-coats-winter-red-used-light-pockets-', 3 ]);
```

Where coats, winter, red, used, light, pockets are the tags (categories) of that page. 
I use php to produce this string.
An other page would have the following for example:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Cat', '-dress-winter-blue-new-light-pockets-', 3 ]);
```

And all these got pushed to a single variable. Now, I cannot find which of the tags has the most hits (the one part of the report I wanted), but I can find how many hits a certain tag has.

To do that, I created a custom report, where I put the metric group "pageviews" and the Dimension drilldowns "Custom Variable (Key 1)", "Custom Variable (Key 1)
Custom Variable (Value 01)", "Page"

Then I run the report, click on the variable "Cat", and filter for -winter- and it gives me how manypageviews I had for articles with the tag "winter".

Dissadvantages:

a) There is a limit of 64 bytes for the combination of custom variable name and value. I have overcome this by not using actually the tags, but their id's
(so, in my real scenario, the values look like -31-39-45-130-168-206-249- but this is good enough for me).

b) You cannot find from inside google analytics which category/tag has the most pageviews. 
(you can always export it though to a csv and work on it in an other script).

Hopefully Google will add a "tags" functionality sometime in the future (am I the only one needing this?)

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution would be to use [custom variables](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html). For example:

```
Category1 = Coats
Category2 = Winter
Category3 = Red
```

The two limitations of this solution are that you are limited to five custom variables per page and that your google analytics queries would get fairly complex as you would need to search across all the category variables to find the specific value you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, I saw the custom variables as well. But each article may (and usually does) belong to 5 to 10 categories. So custom variables dont serve it. The second disadvantage you mention I had thought of solving by doing it as "red=true" and "Winter=true" and "coats=true" so that I would use the customvariable name as the value. But again I cannot do it with the limitation of 5.